# ESP8266 Linux: Programming and Flashing

Tags: linux, esp8266, serial-communication, firmware

So I've recently gotten hold of an ESP8266 chip with a microusb port.
I've been trying to program it with the arduino IDE but need to flash it.
So far I have tried this tutorial [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/update-the-firmware-in-your-esp8266-wi-fi-module/) but when I got to the stage of connecting in putty it would not connect giving me an error message, I tried running putty as root which was succesful however I could not type anything in the console.

I have also tried using the serial monitor in the arduino IDE which also only worked as root.
On this computer I'm currently using linux mint 18.1
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: update: I've managed to flash the board now using the nodemcu pyflasher, which I needed sudo for. Basically all I want now is to be able to access the COM port without running whatever software I need as root.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/read-write-to-a-serial-port-without-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to flash the chip with pyflasher which you can get [here](https://github.com/marcelstoer/nodemcu-pyflasher).
To be able to communicate with the device without root I used this command to add myself to the group which can access serial devices.

```
usermod -a -G dialout MY_USER_NAME
```

Thanks